watch() does not work when its component is instantiated twice
I have a component Gregory that has a QFile component and an editable div. I put a ref() on QFile and a watch() to observe when the user send files because I need to  insert a link to the file sent by user on Gregory’s editable div and for that I use a document.querySelector() to detect where the editable div is, based on its id. The id of the editable div is binded to a Gregory prop itemId:
// Gregory.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div contenteditable :id=”`editor-${itemId}`”>
    </div>
    <QFile v-model=”files” /> 
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang=”ts”>
import { watch, toRefs } from ‘vue’
const props = defineProps({
  itemId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})
const { itemId } = toRefs(props)
const files = ref()

watch(files, () => { 
  if (Number(itemId.value) > 2) {
    console.log(itemId.value)
  }
  // example of what I'm doing on my code
})
</script>

The problem is that I have two instances of Gregory inside the same component:
// Example.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <Gregory item-id="0" />
    <div>
      <!-- some content here -->
      <Gregory item-id="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Gregory from './Gregory.vue'
</script>

and, for some reason, the watch() I wrote there does not work with more than one instance of Gregory, since it uses only the first instance’s props even when triggered on the second instance.
Why does this happens and how do I do to make watch() be able to work on multiple instances of my component?

I don't seem to have the problem you mention, even using Quasar.
From where toRefs is coming from? When I tried to recreate you scenary it gives me an error about this declaration, and you already have access to it via props.itemId so I don't think deserialization here is important.
Check this example that I tweaked a bit, but the watch seem to be working fine for both components.
// Example.js
<template>
  <div>
    <Gregory item-id="0" />
    <div>
      <!-- some content here -->
      <Gregory item-id="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Gregory from './Gregory.vue'
</script>

// Gregory.js
<template>
  <div>
    <div contenteditable :id="`editor-${itemId}`">
    </div>

    <input v-model="files">
    {{ count }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { watch, ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  itemId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})

const files = ref(null)
const count = ref(0)

watch(files, () => { 
  if (Number(itemId.value) > 2) {
    count.value += 1
  } 
})
</script>

Working example here: Vue SFC Playground

I forgot to add the toRefs() import on my example. Fixed it. The problem I'm facing on my project is that when I use watch() on , it works as if the item-id was 0. I also added an itemId usage that gets closer to what I'm facing on my project.

@Fornazari why do you need to use toRefs for itemId? Seem to me the issue is when you are trying to convert a prop to ref, and the value is getting lost there. The value of  the prop should not be modified by the child component, if needed use $emit()

@Fornazari I updated the Working example, and even with the toRefs seems to be working fine. Can you check the condition of your watch so it triggers with number Greater or Equal to 2?

itemId prop isn't modified inside the watch callback. I'll try to work with it without the toRefs().

the proper way to destructure props is noted in the Vue docs (requires the latest version of Vue, v3.5.x)

yes, my project is frozen at Vue 3.4 right now

@Fornazari you are facing a different problem now, or is it still the same one? Have you made changes to your conditional, verified the working example, and still no success?

Yes, unfortunately. The problem is related specifically with the QFile usage.
